# Filtering based on matching string patters

Tags: r, filter

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma","Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Lambda","Tau"), 
                 "group" = c("Alpha is good", "Alpha is good", "Alpha is good", "Beta is bad", "Beta is bad","Beta is bad","Beta is bad","Beta is bad"), 
                 "Val" = c(2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5))
```

I would like to filter observation when the group name matches the id name. In sum, the final dataset should look like this:

```
final <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Beta"), 
                 "group" = c("Alpha is good", "Beta is bad"), 
                 "Val" = c(2,5))
```

The idea is that the function should be able to recognize if the string in "id" is also present in "group".

I hope this is clear

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_detect` which is vectorized (According to `?str_detect`

> Vectorised over string and pattern.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr(
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  filter(str_detect(group, id))
```

---

If there are overlapping elements  in each group

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  group_by(group1 = group) %>%
  filter(str_detect(group, id))
```

Answer (score 0):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
df[unlist(Map(grepl, df$id, df$group)), ]

     id         group Val
1 Alpha Alpha is good   2
5  Beta   Beta is bad   5
```

Or even more elegantly using `mapply()` (based on a comment from @r2evans):

```
df[mapply(grepl, df$id, df$group), ]
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma","Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Lambda","Tau"), 
                 "group" = c("Alpha is good", "Alpha is good", "Alpha is good", "Beta is bad", "Beta is bad","Beta is bad","Beta is bad","Beta is bad"), 
                 "Val" = c(2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Instead of `unlist(Map(...))`, can you just use `mapply(...)`?

Comment: (If you look at the source, `Map` is just a convenience wrapper anyway :-)